# Making div appear depending on Javascript value

Tags: javascript, function

Hi i have created this calculator:

HTML:

```
    <form>
    <p> Boligens byggeår 
        <select id="alder" name="alder">
                <option value="70">Før 1960</option>
                <option value="55">1961-1980</option>
                <option value="40">1981-2000</option>
          <option value="30">2001 og efter</option>
            </select></p>
            <br><br>
<p>Antal m2 
<input type="text" id="m2"/></p>
<br><br>
    <p>Åbenhed
        <select id="aabenhed" name="aabenhed">
                <option value="0.70">Åben</option>
                <option value="0.50">Mellem</option>
            <option value="0.30">Lukket</option>
            </select></p>

<br><br>

    <input type="button" onClick="calc();" value="Beregn" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

<div id="500" style="display:none;">explanatory text 1</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  function calc(){
var alder=document.getElementById('alder').value;
var m2=document.getElementById('m2').value;
var aabenhed=document.getElementById('aabenhed').value;
var resultat=alder*m2*aabenhed/1000;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=resultat;
return false
};
```

And now i want to make a div appear depending on the result.
I already tried doing something like this:

```
    if (result <= 500) {
    document.getElementById('500').style.display = "block";}
```

But that does not work, so i'm stuck about how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: can you show your html too please - we need to see the div that you are trying to show

Comment: I added the HTML :)

Comment: HTML id should not start with a number: [Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: ok your first problem is you have no element with an id of 500

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the id of 500 part, its there now

Comment: ALWAYS give meaningful names to id's, as its unique and must explain what the div is about.

Comment: Ok then, what is `result` and how is it calculated - I'm guessing it's not doing what you think as if you take your code as it stands (without the if), it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/t9ojqf2m/

Comment: "result" is coming from "var resultat=alder*m2*aabenhed/1000;" and then "document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=resultat;"

Comment: try console.log in `if (result <= 500) {` to see if he enters that if.

Comment: Ok, can you show how you get that html back out as you don't have a global to set it - you may need to do a `parseInt()` on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want ??

```js
function calc(){
var alder=document.getElementById('alder').value;
var m2=document.getElementById('m2').value;
var aabenhed=document.getElementById('aabenhed').value;
var resultat=alder*m2*aabenhed/1000;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=resultat;
 if (resultat <= 500) {
    document.getElementById('500').style.display = "block";}  
  else{
    document.getElementById('500').style.display = "none";}  
  
return false
};
```

```html
    <form>
    <p> Boligens byggeår 
        <select id="alder" name="alder">
                <option value="70">Før 1960</option>
                <option value="55">1961-1980</option>
                <option value="40">1981-2000</option>
          <option value="30">2001 og efter</option>
            </select></p>
            <br><br>
<p>Antal m2 
<input type="text" id="m2"/></p>
<br><br>
    <p>Åbenhed
        <select id="aabenhed" name="aabenhed">
                <option value="0.70">Åben</option>
                <option value="0.50">Mellem</option>
            <option value="0.30">Lukket</option>
            </select></p>

<br><br>

    <input type="button" onClick="calc();" value="Beregn" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

<div id="500" style="display:none;">explanatory text 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in that javascript function "calc()" you are holding value into this variable "resultat"

but in if condition , you are using "result" variable to check condition. div element is not getting displayed, as if condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

Your can use Jquery its very simple

Use this CDN link

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    if (result <= 500) {
        $('#div Id').show(); // replace div Id with your div id
    }
```

Comment: jQuery is not the answer for everything - why add a massive library just to show a div?  This question isn't even tagged with jquery

Comment: he didn't add the jquery tag, and its very simple to not require jquery for it.